# Script not working onclick

Tags: html, jscript

I have found a dialog box script http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/ which I want to work with `button` `onclick`. But it's not working.
Any Help?

My modification

```
<input type="button" id="btnOpenDialog" value="Open Confirm Dialog"    onclick="fnOpenNormalDialog()"/>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>

function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");

    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        alert("Confirmed");
    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```

Comment: works fine in the fiddle with IE11

Comment: do you have both jQuery and jQuery-UI included?

Comment: ya.. I am working with jsfiddle only

Comment: Hi all, The problem is with `onload script` I should have called it in body or head. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your javascript functions in  tags to HTML block like this :

```
<input type="button" id="btnOpenDialog" value="Open Confirm Dialog"    onclick="fnOpenNormalDialog()"/>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
<script>
    function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");
    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        alert("Confirmed");
    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
</script>
```

DEMO : 
http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/106/

Comment: Hi Depali, What you have shown is correct and quite similar to what I have done. But the way of implementation is not correct. You should have removed the option onload and called the script portion separately http://jsfiddle.net/alokverma/vvjj8/111/

Comment: you can do it in both ways ! last fiddle is also correct that u sent

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<button value="click me" onclick="fnOpenNormalDialog()">
```

You need to add the brackets for the function call to succeed.